# Can not read request.body without disabling CsrfViewMiddleware

Tags: django, post, csrf

Is there a method to access `request.body` from a POST request in Django, 
without disabling `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`?

Accessing request.body will result in:

```
Exception Type:     RawPostDataException
Exception Value:    You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

I searched and understand that request data stream is first read by the `CsrfViewMiddleware`.

Disabling it, resolves the problem, but this is not a safe solution.

Practically, in normal safe setting situation, Django does not permit accessing raw POST data.

Comment: You could try using the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt`) decorator for that particular view, rather than disabling the middleware for the entire site.

Comment: why would you read it? the sent data is in `request.POST`

Comment: I could not read request.body without disabling csrf middleware.

Comment: I don't want request.POST, I want request.body.

Comment: I want to try to handle multiple file upload from one input field which Django do not permit. Every request.FILES allow me to acces just one file. And, anyway, could be various reasons to access request.body.